# Is it possible to create a (dynamic) byte array in Immediate window, in Excel VBA? (without DIM)

Tags: excel, vba

I know that byte arrays can be created with `Dim x() as Byte`.
I wanted to do it in Immediate Window.
I have searched for how but can't find any answer.

The reason behind this, is I wanted to do something like:

```
x=StrConv("ABCDEF",vbFromUnicode)
```

so that I can get something like (65,66,67,68,69,70) etc. in Immediate Window without a loop and Asc().
I can accomplish this in a module sub (where I can DIM) but I just wanna know how to achieve this in the Immediate Window or is it really impossible.

Why Immediate Window? No reason. I just love Immediate Window.

Answer (score 0):

I found my own answer.
[image: create bytearray]

I got my inspiration from [MOTOBIT's ScriptUtilities.ByteArray](https://www.motobit.com/help/ScptUtl/clu46.htm) object.
It was trial version only and most people won't have it installed on their computers.
I searched the internet and finally found the ?dotNet's System.Text.UTF8Encoding object and it's `getBytes` method.
Still there's an error because getBytes was not found, as dotNet exposes this function as an overload and has to be used as getBytes_4(for string input) as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384741/cant-use-getbytes-and-computehash-methods-on-vba).

The code in the Immediate Windows goes like below:

```vb
set u8=createobject("system.text.utf8encoding"): _
print typename(u8.getbytes_4(range("A1").value)): _
ba=u8.getbytes_4(range("A1").value):print "ba is "&typename(ba): _
for each i in ba:print i,chr(i):next i: _
range("A2").Resize(ubound(ba)+1,1).Value= _
worksheetfunction.Transpose(ba)
```

The code works with Cell A1 containing, a string, in this example, "Stack OverFlow".

I think most of the modern computers will have different dotNet versions installed and hope that this will work in their Office applications' VBA codes.
Even if not so, we just have to tell the user to download and install a compatible version of dotNet rather than asking them to use a trial object from an outside company.

In any case, I am just happy to prove that my question is not pointless/meaningless and there's a working and workable solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
x=Array(Array(1,2,3),Array(4,cbyte(5),6)
?x(1)(1)
 5
?vartype(x(1)(1))
 17
```

Comment: david,thanks for sharing.x & x(1) in what you've shown are fixed length array.Using Array() function cannot accomodate variable length strings for example.Moreover,?typename(x) and ?typename(x(1)) will return Variant().Your answer will return Variant arrays containing bytes as elements.They will never be Byte() like DIM x() as Byte.

Comment: david, please try the code below in Immediate window.I hope you will understand what I meant.
'(code starts)
s="abc":va=array(0,cbyte(1),2):?typename(va),:va=split(strconv(s,64),chr$(0)):?typename(va),typename(va(0)),ubound(va),va(0),:s=join(va,"-")&"d":?s: _
set u8=createobject("system.text.unicodeencoding"):x=u8.getbytes_4(s): _
z=strreverse(x):y=x:?typename(x),typename(y),typename(z),ubound(x),x(ubound(x)-1)&"="&chr(x(ubound(x)-1)),:?x &"|" &y &"|" &z
'(code ends)

Comment: Please refer to the imgur image (linked below) as code formatting is not respected in SO comments.
https://imgur.com/a/tPAlReF