# Macro in excel to encrypt a cell password in MD5

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

In my sheet excel named as Sheet1 I have a table as below:

[excel table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQKLg.png)

For this table I write a macro to convert al cell in column Password in MD5, below the macro code:

```
Sub EncryptPasswords()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim result As String
    
    ' Set the worksheet object
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Modify the worksheet name as per your data
    
    ' Set the range for the "Password" column
    Set rng = ws.Range("D5:D12") ' Modify the range as per your data
    
    For Each cell In rng
        If Not IsEmpty(cell.Value) Then
            result = MD5EncryptCellValue(cell.Value)
            If Left(result, 5) = "Error" Then
                cell.Value = result ' If an error occurs, display the error message in the cell
            Else
                cell.Value = result ' Assign the encrypted value to the cell
            End If
        End If
    Next cell
End Sub

Function MD5EncryptCellValue(inputValue As String) As String
    On Error Resume Next
    
    Dim md5Obj As Object
    Set md5Obj = CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider")
    
    Dim textToBytes() As Byte
    textToBytes = StrConv(inputValue, vbFromUnicode)
    
    Dim hashedBytes() As Byte
    hashedBytes = md5Obj.ComputeHash(textToBytes)
    
    Dim i As Long
    Dim result As String
    For i = LBound(hashedBytes) To UBound(hashedBytes)
        result = result & Right("0" & Hex(hashedBytes(i)), 2)
    Next i
    
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        MD5EncryptCellValue = "Error: " & Err.Description
        Err.Clear
    Else
        MD5EncryptCellValue = result
    End If
End Function
```

During execution the result for all the cell in column Password is

> Error: Subscript out of range

The range from D5 to D12 is correct. How can I solve?

Comment: Remove the statement `On Error Resume Next`, run the code and watch where exactly the code fails. The debugger can help you understand what the problem is.

Comment: If I continue without the statement a popup tell me "Invalid procedure call or argument error", and the debug report the instruction hashedBytes = md5Obj.ComputeHash(textToBytes)

Comment: Have a look to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36384741/cant-use-getbytes-and-computehash-methods-on-vba

Answer (score 1):

Based on other scripts to generate hash keys, I notice that changing:

```
hashedBytes = md5Obj.ComputeHash(textToBytes)
```

to

```
hashedBytes = md5Obj.ComputeHash_2(textToBytes)
```

resolves the issue. I guess the original `ComputeHash` has been deprecated?